# Fully functional HTML5 file explorer?

Tags: library, html, file-management, css

I'd want to bring my desktop file explorer to a browser, without losing too much functionalities. I'm using Nemo on Ubuntu.

I'd want to be able to add remote server, to have a shell, shortcuts and helpers, views, ... available in desktop file explorers.

I am especially looking for a responsive library which could help me to display the items (files and directories), in different views and allowing operations on it (sort, filter,search, creation, ...).

Something like that:

[image]
[image]

I have found [listjs.com](http://listjs.com) which seems quite good for that, but it is almost focus on data, I would also want something who manage the display.

Answer (score 2):

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) is what I was looking for.

It have sorting and filtering functions, and some useful layout modes:

Vertical layout
[image: Vertical layout]

And several [bin-packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) layouts
[image]
[image]
[image]

It uses also css animations for sorting or filtering and seems a well-structured and optimised library.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. Especially answers should show explicitly how the OP's requirements are met, and what makes the product recommendable (e.g. personal experiences).

Comment: As I was responding to myself, I did not think to make an improved answer:) I will try to add some details.

Comment: That would be great, Gael! Even though answering yourself (which is perfectly fine), it will be much more helpful to others then :)

Comment: Seen years later, no one else has answered .   I think that it wood be safe for OP to accept their own answer ;-)